# SSL Issue on curl by compiling PHP7

Tags: php, compiling, ssl, curl

While compiling PHP7 with curl I got this message in my log:

> /php-src/ext/curl/interface.c:74:5: warning: #warning "libcurl was compiled with SSL support, but configure could not determine which" "library was used; thus no SSL crypto locking callbacks will be set, which may " "cause random crashes on SSL requests" [-Wcpp]
>    warning \
>   ^

After that ki installed OpenSSL and added that to my configure Parameters too, but that doesn't solve my issue.

I am not able to get the clue...
would be great to get a hint from the community.

Thank you!
Chris

Comment: Libssl-dev is already installed.

Comment: You solved that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try install `curl` with `openssl` support from source:

```
yum install -y openssl-devel
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.65.3.tar.gz
tar xvfz curl-7.65.3.tar.gz
cd curl-7.65.3
./configure --with-ssl
make
make install
```

*(maybe needed restart your console)*

```
# curl -V
curl 7.65.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.65.3 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips zlib/1.2.7
Release-Date: 2019-07-19
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SSL UnixSockets
```